# Autosys jobs hung

Tags: autosys

We have jobs getting stuck in autosys R11 screen due to app server down

So is there any way to monitor autoys itself is up and running

Note-The jobs which got stuck shows completed in database but the dependent jobs cannot start though from front end the jobs are still in runnig status

Please help

Answer (score 0):

1. `chk_auto_up` command will check if application server, event server,
   scheduler and agent are working fine.
2. `chase` command checks if agent is running fine.
3. `autoping` command checks if agent is able to communicate with the
   application server.
4. Check the log files of components by below commands :

   `autosyslog -e (scheduler)
   autosyslog -s (server)
   autosyslog -d j (job)`
5. check the status of each components manually by below commands

   `unisrvcntr status waae_server.$AUTOSERV
   unisrvcntr status waae_agent-$AGENT_NAME
   unisrvcntr status waae_webserver.$AUOTSERV
   unisrvcntr status waae_sched.$AUTOSERV`